# How can I insert the minus symbol in this array?

Tags: formatting, align

I want to insert minus symbol like this picture
[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
  \makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overtabline}{%
  \noalign{%
        \vskip-.5\dimexpr\ht\@arstrutbox+\dp\@arstrutbox\relax

    \vskip10pt\relax
    \hrule
    \vskip-0.5pt\relax
    \vskip0.5\dimexpr\ht\@arstrutbox+\dp\@arstrutbox\relax
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}cccc}
S &=&{} ab + & (a+d) bq&+& (a+2d) bq^2 &+&  \cdots &+& (a+nd)bq^n \\
qS &=& & a b q &+& (a+d)bq^2&+&\cdots &+& (a+(n-1)d)bq^n &+& (a+nd)bq^{n+1}\\
\overtabline
S(1-q) &=& ab + &dbq &+& dbq^2 &+& \cdots &+& dbq^n &-& (a+nd)bq^{n+1}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the minus should be between the lines and extra long as in your picture, you might do

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
  \makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overtabline}{%
  \noalign{%
        \vskip-.5\dimexpr\ht\@arstrutbox+\dp\@arstrutbox\relax

    \vskip10pt\relax
    \hrule
    \vskip-0.5pt\relax
    \vskip0.5\dimexpr\ht\@arstrutbox+\dp\@arstrutbox\relax
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}cccc}
S &=&{} ab + & (a+d) bq&+& (a+2d) bq^2 &+&  \cdots &+& (a+nd)bq^n \\
\smash{\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{8pt}{---}}}qS &=& & a b q &+& (a+d)bq^2&+&\cdots &+& (a+(n-1)d)bq^n &+& (a+nd)bq^{n+1}\\
\overtabline
S(1-q) &=& ab + &dbq &+& dbq^2 &+& \cdots &+& dbq^n &-& (a+nd)bq^{n+1}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different solution, which (a) places the large minus symbol to the left of the second row, (b) right-aligns the column contents for better readability (in terms of powers of `$q$`), and (c) replaces `\overtabline` with `\cmidrule` (from the `booktabs` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this the default with up-to-date LaTeX formats since Apr. 2018
\usepackage{amsmath,fourier}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,relsize} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for +, -, and = columns
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{@{} l *{6}{rC} r @{}}
& S &=& ab &+& (a+d) bq &+& (a+2d)bq^2 &+& \cdots &+&     (a+nd)bq^n \\
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{-}}} &
qS  &=&  &&         abq &+&  (a+d)bq^2 &+& \cdots &+& (a+(n-1)d)bq^n &+& (a+nd)bq^{n+1}\\
\cmidrule{2-14}
& S(1-q)&=& ab &+&  dbq &+&      dbq^2 &+& \cdots &+& dbq^n          &-& (a+nd)bq^{n+1}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I put minus like my picture?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - If this were my document, I would *not* raise the enlarged minus symbol. However, there's nothing stopping you from using @marmot's method, i.e., writing `\smash{\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{8pt}{$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{-}}}$}}}`, right?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I use your answer for my document.

Comment: Please explain for me mean of the line `\begin{array}{@{} l *{6}{rC} r @{}}`. I understand that, all columns are  right-aligns? If I want to align of each column, for example, first column if left, second in center, ... How can I do?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - The`array` contains 14 columns in all: The first is left-aligned (`l`), for the large minus symbol. Then there are 6 pairs of `rC`, where `r` means right-aligned and `C` means centered (in a special way, suitable for operators such as `+`, `-`,  and `=`). The final, 14th, column is right-aligned.

Comment: this code \setlength\arraycolsep{1.2 pt}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{8}{rC} r @{}}
&3S=& && 2\cdot 3 &+& 7\cdot 3^2 &+& 12\cdot 3^3 &+& 17\cdot 3^4 &+&  \cdots &+& 497 \cdot 3 ^{100} &+& 502 \cdot 3^{101}\\
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{-}}}
&S=&  2\cdot 1 &+& 7\cdot 3 &+& 12\cdot 3^2 &+& 17\cdot 3^3  &+& 22 \cdot 3 ^{4}  &+& \cdots &+& 502 \cdot 3^{100}\\
\cmidrule{2-17}
&2S =& -2 &-& 5\cdot 3 &-& 5\cdot 3^2 &-& 5\cdot 3^3  &-& 5\cdot 3^4 &-& \cdots &-& 5 \cdot 3^{100} &+& 502 \cdot 3^{101}
\end{array}
\]
not align `r` at `7\cdot 3^2` and `12\cdot 3^2`.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Your code is missing three instances of `&`. Change all 3 instances of  `S=&` to `S&=&`. You should also change `\cmidrule{2-17}` to `\cmidrule{2-18}`.